# jquery in firebug throws always NULL

Tags: jquery, firebug

I am just learning how to use firebug properly. I watched a howto and the author simply typed $('p'); in the console and it displayed all the p tags. In my case even there are many p tags on that site (my local Drupal 7 Site) it always shows NULL. Also with all other tags I've tried. I have to put another $ in front and this kinda works?! What did I wrong that the other way did not work?

Comment: may be your site don't include jQuery library.

Comment: Sounds like you've included MooTools, which uses `$(id)` to select by an ID and `$$(selector)` to select by a selector (such as `"p"`).

Comment: I assume every Drupal 7 Site has jquery, however the jQuerify button tells me "This page already using jQuery v1.4.4". I dont have MooTools or anything like that, just Firefox 12.0 with Firebug and Firequery.

Answer (score 2):

The previous example didn't do anything because it was not returning or printing anything.
Try this:

```
(function($) {
   console.log('this works');
   return $('p');
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Yes, this is the price we have to pay for javascript plugin compatibility :P

Answer (score 1):

Any jQuery process will execute in browser `console` if your site have included jQuery library, otherwise you can't get any `console`.

It's not possible to jQuery get `NULL`, because if no element exists it will return `[]`. Or, you may get `undefined`, but `NULL` never ever.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(function($) {
    $('p');
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: >>> (function($) { $('p'); })(jQuery);
undefined

Comment: ye I have to wrap it into this in firebug console as well but still gives me undefined back...

Comment: Try `(function($){return $('p');})(jQuery);` instead

Answer (score 0):

Try issuing the following commands in the Firebug console:

```
jQuery.toSource()
$.toSource()
```

If you have jQuery included on the page, they should both return the same non-null value, namely, a chunk of source code as a string.

If you don't have JQuery included in the page, then it's tricky: `$` in the Firebug console is an internal **function of [Firebug command line API](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Command_Line_API)**
which is a simple shortcut for `document.getElementById()` that is not that powerful as JQuery's `$` and they don't work the same way. Then, `$('p')` looks for element with `id="p"` in HTML source code. There aren't any, so you get null.

`$$` is yet another function of Firebug command line API, which on the contrary works as a CSS selector. Then, `$$('p')` gives you an array of all `<p>` elements from HTML source.